# h5py hdf5 extract an attribute from group members into a list

Tags: python, list, attributes, hdf5, h5py

Problem:
I want to extract the attribute of each member of a hdf5 file group  into a list (actually not exactly as you will see but that is irrelevant for the problem, so I keep it simple).

I thought the visit function is the most efficient way for that. I can print the results but I don't manage to append the results to a list.

This is the function to be called by 'visit':

```
def func(name,obj):

   attribute = obj.attr.get('attribute_group')
   if attribute == 2:
       result = name
       print(result)
```

This is the visit function which applies the  function func to alll members of the group.

```
file = h5py.File(filepath,'r')
obj = file['/channel_groups/0/clusters/main/']
obj.visit(func)
```

So far so good. But how do I save the result read out in every iteration?

Solutions that do not work:

1. adding `return result` to the end of the function makes the function stop after returning the first result - as stated in the documentation.
2. Incorporating the appendment to the list in 'visit' gives an error.

   `results = []
   obj.visit(results.append(func(obj,results))
   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`
3. feeding the list to the function and append it inside it also does not work:

   `results = []
   obj.visit(func(results))
   TypeError: func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'obj'`

Or
    `obj.visit(func(obj,results))
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

Is it not possible? I want to avoid calling every single member in a loop because this takes time.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I haven't used the `visit` method much, and would have to play with it to get the 'callback' function right.  But I don't think it's any faster than looping explicitly (assuming the group just has a flat layer of datasets).

Comment: I'm a little surprised that your `visit(func)` works.  According to the docs, and my testing, the `visit` function only takes one argument, the `name`.

Comment: Are you sure `obj.attr.get` works?  I have to use `obj[name].attrs.get`.

Comment: After restarting it actually does not work anymore with obj next to the name  in the function definition but also is not necessary. I am using jupyter notebook and something must have been confused.
obj.attr.get  does work.

Answer (score 0):

[How can I loop over HDF5 groups in Python removing rows according to a mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50027646/how-can-i-loop-over-hdf5-groups-in-python-removing-rows-according-to-a-mask)

does the list append right  (there are other examples of `[h5py] visit`).

The argument for `visit` must be callable, i.e. a function:

```
results = []
obj.visit(results.append(func(obj,results))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

`results.append(....)` is a complete function call, which `python` performs before even calling `visit`.  The result of that list append is `None` (the append is in-place).  So effectively you are just doing

```
results=[]
results.append(func(obj, results))
obj.visit(None)
```

I think you need something like

```
def func(name,obj):
   attribute = obj.attr.get('attribute_group')
   if attribute == 2:
       result = name
       print(result)
       results.append(result)
obj.visit(func)
```

Remember, the argument that you give `visit` must be an unevaluated function, not the result of some function call.  It has to be `callable`.

---

I created a file with one group and two datasets

```
In [24]: results = []
In [25]: f.visit(results.append)
In [26]: results
Out[26]: ['agroup', 'agroup/bar', 'agroup/foo']
```

Looking at both name and the referenced object:

```
In [27]: def func(name):
    ...:     print(name, f[name])
    ...:     
In [28]: f.visit(func)
agroup <HDF5 group "/agroup" (2 members)>
agroup/bar <HDF5 dataset "bar": shape (6,), type "<i8">
agroup/foo <HDF5 dataset "foo": shape (3,), type "<i8">
```

or with a more complex func:

```
def func(name):
    obj = f[name]
    attr = list(obj.attrs.items())
    print(name, obj, attr)
    x = obj.attrs.get('x',None)
    if x:     # not none
        results.append((name, x))
In [35]: results=[]
In [36]: f.visit(func)
agroup <HDF5 group "/agroup" (2 members)> []
agroup/bar <HDF5 dataset "bar": shape (6,), type "<i8"> [('x', 10)]
agroup/foo <HDF5 dataset "foo": shape (3,), type "<i8"> [('x', 1)]
In [37]: results
Out[37]: [('agroup/bar', 10), ('agroup/foo', 1)]
```

---

Looking again at the Group docs I see there's a `visititems` method:

```
def func(name, obj):
    attr = list(obj.attrs.items())
    print(name, obj, attr)
    x = obj.attrs.get('x',None)
    if x:     # not none
        results.append((name, x))

In [45]: results=[]
In [46]: f.visititems(func)
agroup <HDF5 group "/agroup" (2 members)> []
agroup/bar <HDF5 dataset "bar": shape (6,), type "<i8"> [('x', 10)]
agroup/foo <HDF5 dataset "foo": shape (3,), type "<i8"> [('x', 1)]
In [47]: results
Out[47]: [('agroup/bar', 10), ('agroup/foo', 1)]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. 
Your suggestion to append to the results list inside the function is what I tried but you need to define results as an empty list outside the function and then bring it into the function. Otherwise it will not recognise it. I tried this in point 3. But didn't completely explain it there.

Comment: You don't need to pass `results` to `func`.  The `results` list is in the global environment.  The error message in 3 comes from the `func(results)` expression.  It doesn't even get to the `visit` step.  There's no such thing as a delayed function call in Python.

Comment: That should solve it. I didn't know that you could set global variables in a python script. Thanks. It works in the notebook.

Comment: You can modify globals.  `results = ...` would not work, but `results.append...` does.  Or `results[i] = ...`.  The key is that a list is `mutable`, modifiable without changing its `id`.